# How can I create an href link to target a DFS location?

Tags: html, hyperlink, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have a need on an intranet project to create hyperlinks which target files on a DFS location. Now there was a time when for example file://c:\directory\filname.txt would work fine but now I need to use locations like this:

```
\\companydomain.com\files\sharename\subfolder\filename.txt
```

this will not work for me using the file:// link format. (amazingly the company internal web browser is chrome, and yes I take credit for pushing that one :-)

Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Chrome is preventing the internal link for security reasons.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16992

Comment #12 has the fix.  Use all forward slashes.

> Our canonical representation of a UNC
>   path is:
>   "file://server/share/foo/bar"

Comment: Sorry but that does not work. Have tried our UNC and DFS paths with that.

Comment: What about modifying the # of slashes after `file:`?  `///` or more?

Comment: Hi Jason, same problem, it would appear I need to use an addin like this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida#